# GitBash doesn't see a directory

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I created git repository in empty folder "Lessons", then placed folder "src" in the same folder, but the command "git status" doesn't show directory "src". What should I do to detect this folder with "git status"?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkkqm.png)

I tried "git add.", "git add --all", but nothing helped me, unfortunately.
The folder "src" is not empty and contains a lot of other directories and java files.

Comment: Is there anything in `src`? Git won't track empty directories.

Comment: The folder "src" is not empty and contains a lot of other directories and java files.

Comment: Try `git check-ignore src`.

Comment: At first, I creatd git repository in folder "Lessons", then just placed folder "src" with other nested directories and files in this directory. Moreover, I don't have .gitignore file, therefore command "git check-ignore src" didn;t help either.

Comment: I add empty text file and git started to see this folder.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Git does no track empty folders by design.

A best pratice for **gitters** to track empty folders is to add a dummy file name `.gitkeep`, that you will remove as soon as you will put a file inside that folder.